# Taiwlind bg-transparent not coming through

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following select:

```
  <select
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
    className="block appearance-none bg-transparent pr-5 pl-2 text-base font-bold md:hidden md:pl-0"
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <option value={option} key={option}>
        {option}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

however the only property that is not being applied is the `bg-transparent` and I can't figure out why

[image]

Comment: Were you looking for this?
`bg-opacity-50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a custom config option like so:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{tsx,ts}"],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: {
        0: "transparent"
      }
...
```

in order to use it with `appearance-none`